# Getting first / last date of the week

Tags: php, datetime

Is it possible to get the first / last date of a week using PHP's [Relative Date Time format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)?

I've tried to do:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$date = new DateTime();

$date->modify('first day of this week'); // to get the current week's first date
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // outputs 2011-12-19

$date->modify('first day of week 50'); // to get the first date of any week by weeknumber
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // outputs 2011-12-18

$date->modify('last day of this week'); // to get the current week's last date
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // outputs 2011-12-17

$date->modify('last day of week 50'); // to get the last date of any week by weeknumber
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // outputs 2011-12-18
```

As you can [see](http://codepad.org/NnqZTDxc) it doesn't output the correct dates.

According to [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) this should be possible if I'm correct.

Am I doing something terrible wrong?

**EDIT**

I need to use PHP's DateTime for dates in the far future.

**UPDATE**

It gets only stranger now. I've done some more testing.

Windows PHP 5.3.3

```
2011-12-01

Warning: DateTime::modify() [datetime.modify]: Failed to parse time string (first day of week 50) at position 13 (w): The timezone could not be found in the database in C:\Users\Gerrie\Desktop\ph\Websites\Charts\www.charts.com\public\index.php on line 9
2011-12-01
2011-11-30

Warning: DateTime::modify() [datetime.modify]: Failed to parse time string (last day of week 50) at position 12 (w): The timezone could not be found in the database in C:\Users\Gerrie\Desktop\ph\Websites\Charts\www.charts.com\public\index.php on line 15
2011-11-30
```

Linux 5.3.8

```
2011-12-01
2011-12-01
2011-11-30
2011-11-30
```

Comment: Doesn't this like depend on the locale, if sunday or monday is the first day of a week?

Comment: @mario: I don't know you tell me. Either way the first two should output the same thing. Same goes for the last two IMHO. Whether it starts on a sunday / monday

Comment: I have an answer for this using IntlCalendar [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75184376/9811172).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to docs the format strings "first day of" and "last day of" are only allowed for months, not for weeks. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

If you combine first and last day of with a week statement the result either blows the parser or is something that you did not expect (usually the first or last day of a month, not a week).

The difference that you see between Win and Linux is probably only because of different error reporting settings.

To get the first and last day of the current week use:

```
$date->modify('this week');
$date->modify('this week +6 days');
```

To get the first and last day of week 50 use:

```
$date->setISODate(2011, 50);
$date->setISODate(2011, 50, 7);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the modify method for absolute week numbers you have to use the formats defined in http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php:

```
$date->modify('2011W50');
$date->modify('2011W50 +6 days');
```

Comment: You might be right on that. Although I don't see where it states it can only be used for months though (might be just me needing some sleep :) ). BTW error reporting is the same on both machines. So what you are saying it that it is only possible the get the first / last date of the current (possible also next, previous etc) week and not by weeknumber? (I know I can calculate it myself just thought this would be neater)

Comment: The docs say:

_'first day' ' of'?

Sets the day of the first of the current month. This phrase is best used together with a month name following it._

Comment: And yes, you can also use the modify() method to get absolute weeks. See my edit above.

Comment: great now where are getting somewhere. Just one last thing. If I use `2011W50` it doesn't get the current weeks dates (it is ISO week 50 now). I get the correct dates when I use `2011W48`. Any ideas?

Comment: the `setISODate` worked for me though. Might want to review the modify or remove it completely to help other users finding this question. Or should it just work?

Comment: modify('2011W50') works perfectly for me - returns 2011-12-12 which is identical to the result of setISODate(2011, 50).
Tested on PHP 5.3.8, Windows 7 64.

Answer (score 53):

I'm a big fan of using the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library, which makes this sort of thing really easy. For example:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$monday = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()
$sunday = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()
```

Or, if you'd prefer to have Sunday be the first day of your week:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

Carbon::setWeekStartsAt(Carbon::SUNDAY);
Carbon::setWeekEndsAt(Carbon::SATURDAY);

$sunday = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()
$saturday = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()
```

Comment: This seems to be the only date library that actually works.

Comment: this is the solution

Answer (score 7):

if first day of week is Monday

```
$date->modify('Monday this week');
```

else if first day is Sunday

```
$date->modify('Sunday this week');
```

because in different countries first day of week maybe Monday or Sunday

Comment: This is wrong. Because 'Sunday this week' will be first day of NEXT week in countries where they use Sunday as the first day of week

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am using to get the first and last day of the week from **any date**.
In this case, monday is the first day of the week...

```
$date = date('Y-m-d'); // you can put any date you want
$nbDay = date('N', strtotime($date));
$monday = new DateTime($date);
$sunday = new DateTime($date);
$monday->modify('-'.($nbDay-1).' days');
$sunday->modify('+'.(7-$nbDay).' days');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getweek_first_last_date($date)
{
    $cur_date = strtotime($date); // Change to whatever date you need
    // Get the day of the week: Sunday = 0 to Saturday = 6
    $dotw = date('w', $cur_date);
    if($dotw>1)
    {
        $pre_monday  =  $cur_date-(($dotw-1)*24*60*60);
        $next_sunday = $cur_date+((7-$dotw)*24*60*60);
    }
    else if($dotw==1)
    {
        $pre_monday  = $cur_date;
        $next_sunday =  $cur_date+((7-$dotw)*24*60*60);
    }
    else if($dotw==0)
    {
        $pre_monday  =$cur_date -(6*24*60*60);;
        $next_sunday = $cur_date;
    }

    $date_array =   array();
    $date_array['start_date_of_week'] = $pre_monday;
    $date_array['end_date_of_week'] = $next_sunday;

    return $date_array;
}

$date = '2013-12-22';
getweek_first_last_date($date);


Output :
$array_of_week = Array
(
    [start_date_of_week] => 1387152000
    [end_date_of_week] => 1387670400
)

$start_date =date('d/m/Y', $array_of_week['start_date_of_week'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
function getlastweek_first_last_date()
{
   $cur_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // Change to whatever date you need
    // Get the day of the week: Sunday = 0 to Saturday = 6
    $previousweekcurdate  = $cur_date - (7*24*3600);
    $cur_date = $previousweekcurdate;
    $dotw = date('w', $cur_date);
    if($dotw>1)
    {
        $pre_sunday  =  $cur_date-(($dotw-1)*24*60*60) - (24*60*60);
        $next_satday = $cur_date+((7-$dotw)*24*60*60)- (24*60*60);
    }
    else if($dotw==1)
    {
        $pre_sunday  = $cur_date- (24*60*60);
        $next_satday =  $cur_date+((7-$dotw)*24*60*60)- (24*60*60);
    }
    else if($dotw==0)
    {
        $pre_sunday  =$cur_date -(6*24*60*60)- (24*60*60);
        $next_satday = $cur_date- (24*60*60);
    }

    $pre_sunday = date('Y-m-d',$pre_sunday)." 00:00:00";
    $next_satday = date('Y-m-d',$next_satday)." 23:59:59";
    $date_array =   array();
    $date_array['sdoflw'] = $pre_sunday;
    $date_array['edoflw'] = $next_satday;

    return $date_array;
}

$date_array = getlastweek_first_last_date();
echo $start_date_of_week = $date_array['sdoflw'];
echo $end_date_of_week = $date_array['edoflw'];

</code>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simply you can get the date as follows**

first day of week is Monday

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Monday this week'));
```

if first day is Sunday

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Sunday this week'));
```