# Find first and last week days according to locale

Tags: php, datetime, localization

I'm trying to find first and last week days based on the locale.

In U.S.A. a week normally starts on Sunday, but in other countries it could start on another day - e.g. Monday or even Saturday.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

$start_week = (new DateTimeImmutable());
$start_week = $start_week->modify('this week');
$end_week = $start_week->modify('this week +6 days');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$week_range = new DatePeriod($start_week, $interval, $end_week);

foreach($week_range as $week_day) {
  // $week_day starts with Monday, supposed to be Sunday
}
```

Comment: 'Start of week' on calendars is very often a user preference on top of a cultural default. Even if you're living in the US, you may wish your calendar display to start weeks on a Monday.

Comment: @Leith: My Windows, Outlook, iPhone calendars all start on Sunday. Developers of those calendars didn't have such excuse.

Comment: And yet your Google calendar will let you pick. I'm not saying it's not a good idea to have a default based on locale - I'm just saying you don't necessarily want to set it in stone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the [`IntlCalendar`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php) class. It has a method [`getFirstDayofWeek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.getfirstdayofweek.php), which returns an integer, corresponding to the **`DOW_`** constants in [IntlCalendar](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php):

> ```
> const integer DOW_SUNDAY = 1 ;
> const integer DOW_MONDAY = 2 ;
> const integer DOW_TUESDAY = 3 ;
> const integer DOW_WEDNESDAY = 4 ;
> const integer DOW_THURSDAY = 5 ;
> const integer DOW_FRIDAY = 6 ;
> const integer DOW_SATURDAY = 7 ;
> ```

Use that to add days to the start day when calling `DateTimeImmutable::modify()` for the start day. See it in action with three locales (i.e. *en_US*, *es_ES*, *sw_KE*) in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4rn0-e6e7).

```
$locale = 'es_ES'; //Spain Spanish locale
$cal1 = IntlCalendar::createInstance(NULL, $locale);
$firstDayOfWeek = $cal1->getFirstDayOfWeek();
$daysToAdd = $firstDayOfWeek - 2; //difference from US M-Sunday 
echo 'locale: '.$local.' first day of week: '.$cal1->getFirstDayOfWeek().' days to add: '.$daysToAdd.'<br />';
$start_week = new DateTimeImmutable();
$start_week = $start_week->modify('this week +'.$daysToAdd.' days');
$end_week = $start_week->modify('+6 days');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$week_range = new DatePeriod($start_week, $interval, $end_week);

foreach($week_range as $week_day) {
    echo 'week day: '.$week_day->format('l m/d/Y').'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I think this is the *only* native way to do it in PHP: `IntlCalendar` uses [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), which in turn uses the robust [CLDR database](http://cldr.unicode.org/). `DateTime`, on the other hand, uses the [Olson zoneinfo database](https://blog.jonudell.net/2009/10/23/a-literary-appreciation-of-the-olsonzoneinfotz-database/), which doesn't contain start of week information.

Comment: Good solution. But how do I avoid using relative times like `'this week'`. I need to use my `$start_week` object later. In other words I want to be able to determine first day of week at any date of the object (i.e. `$start_week = $start_week->setTimestamp($my_ts)`).

Comment: Hmm does that mean `$my_ts` would have various dates (e.g. _07/04/1776_) and we would need to know what day of the week that is? So then would we need to find the difference between that day of the week number and the _local_ first day of the week? Can you outline a scenario?

Comment: Basically I just needed an object to manipulate... `$intl_cal = IntlCalendar::createInstance(NULL, $locale); $days_to_add = $intl_cal->getFirstDayOfWeek() - 2; $first_day_of_week = (new DateTimeImmutable())->setTime(00,00,00)->modify('this week +' . $days_to_add . ' days')->format('l'); // Sunday`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[IntlCalendar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php) can do all that, but it's not well documented.

Other answers use some hardcoded values, this doesn't.

```php
$date = new DateTime('now');
$locale = 'en_US';

$thisWeek = IntlCalendar::fromDateTime($date, $locale);
$thisWeek->set(IntlCalendar::FIELD_DAY_OF_WEEK, $thisWeek->getFirstDayOfWeek());
// $thisWeek now points to the first day of the week
$weekStart = $thisWeek->toDateTime();

$daysToAdvance = $thisWeek->getMaximum(IntlCalendar::FIELD_DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
// Maximum number of days in a week minus 1 gets you to the last day
$weekEnd = $weekStart->modify("+{$daysToAdvance} days");

$previousWeek = IntlCalendar::fromDateTime($date, $locale);
$previousWeek->add(IntlCalendar::FIELD_WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
$previousWeek = $previousWeek->toDateTime();

$nextWeek = IntlCalendar::fromDateTime($date, $locale);
$nextWeek->add(IntlCalendar::FIELD_WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
$nextWeek = $nextWeek->toDateTime();
```